# Force Azure Re-Authentication for each request in C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have a requirement where I want to fetch the Authorization Code for `Azure` login for each request in web API. As of now once the user signs in to Azure, after that I am not getting the authorization code as the user is already signed in.
How can I force the user to sign in again? This is the code I have been using as of now in the owin_startup file in `web API`?

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    CookieSecure = (CookieSecureOption)Convert.ToInt32(cookieSecure), //  CookieSecureOption.NeverAlways
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
    CookieHttpOnly = false,
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = Authority,
    RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
});
```

Comment: Hi @DCZ. Can you please explain why this is required? Why can't you use the access token, which is issued as result of authentication, for as long as it hasn't expired?

Answer (score 1):

According to the code and the cases you post before, I think it it not about Azure ad b2c, so here I will give a reply for azure ad.

When you request an authorization code, there is a `prompt=login` property which is indicate **the user should be prompted to reauthenticate**.

Also here is an article about [Forcing reauthentication with Azure AD](https://hajekj.net/2017/03/06/forcing-reauthentication-with-azure-ad/) which suggest use [Token Max Age](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-policy-property-details) to achieve it.

You can append max_age= to the authorization URL (or just put 0 to force password authentication at all times). So once user gets redirected to the URL, they will be presented with an information to login again.

```
public class RequireReauthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    private int _timeElapsedSinceLast;
    public RequireReauthenticationAttribute(int timeElapsedSinceLast)
    {
        _timeElapsedSinceLast = timeElapsedSinceLast;
    }
    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var foundAuthTime = int.TryParse(context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(AppClaimTypes.AuthTime)?.Value, out int authTime);

        if (foundAuthTime && DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimestamp() - authTime < _timeElapsedSinceLast)
        {
            await next();
        }
        else
        {
            var state = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "reauthenticate", "true" } };
            await context.HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties(state)
            {
                RedirectUri = context.HttpContext.Request.Path
            }, ChallengeBehavior.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the reason you wish to re-authenticate the user is to get/refresh the token in memory even when the auth cookie is present. Simplest way to achieve this would be decorate your controller with the `AuthorizeForScopes` attribute. You can check the sample project on [Github here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/)